# How to implement ScrollToAsync on ScrollView which is in an item of ListView - Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, scrollview, scrollto

I have a ListView with a Label and a custom made Horizontal List of some numbers in each cell.

Horizontal List - have added Labels as children to StackLayout and StackLayout as child to ScrollView.

And I am getting horizontal list scrolled and when I click on any item of horizontal list, the value is displaying on Label nicely.(Implemented TapGesture on list)

what I need is, I want to implement ScrollToAsync on scrollview, so that if I click on any number on horizontal list, the selected number must automatically scrolled to the center.. is my first question. And then the selected number must be highlighted is the second one..

Please suggest me how and where to implement this line ScrollToAsync in my code.

```
hScroll.ScrollToAsync(sLayout.Children[index], ScrollToPosition.Center, true);
```

Hope you understand the scenario, if you want anything in detail/code please ask me..

Any help would be greatly appreciable. Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I bind index value to element param in ScrollToAsync property of ScrollView - xamarin forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43995931/how-can-i-bind-index-value-to-element-param-in-scrolltoasync-property-of-scrollv)